# Proper way of reading from a HttpWebResponse and .NET 4.0 Framework

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, httpwebresponse

We are currently experiencing a problem reading a ResponseStream that we have had no issues with in the past.  Since adding .NET 4.0 Framwework to our server last night and assigning IIS to use the new framework we are experiencing a few different exceptions when trying to read the responseStream using the following statement (responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();).  Everything up to that point works completely fine.  So, I am looking for changes/improvements on how to read from the response.  I have pasted the code below that we are using and the exceptions we are experiencing.

### Our environment is:

.NET Framework 4.0
Windows Server 2003

### THE CODE:

```
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse;
        Stream responseStream;
        //Accept All Certificate Policy 
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };

        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(theUrl));
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        httpRequest.Timeout = timeOut;


        try
        {
            httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        }
```

### THE EXCEPTIONS:

'httpResponse.GetResponseStream().Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' long {System.NotSupportedException}

'httpResponse.GetResponseStream().Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' long {System.NotSupportedException}

{"This stream does not support seek operations."} System.SystemException {System.NotSupportedException}

---

Regards,

Mike

Comment: Well I'm not sure if its the cause of your problem, but you are using Method="POST" without sending any data.  I think you might want "GET"

Answer (score 6):

You haven't shown the bit of code which tries to use the length - but basically, you aren't guaranteed that you'll *know* the length of the stream. The server may not have given a content-length header.

If you need to mess with the stream, it's probably best to just copy all the data into a `MemoryStream`. With .NET 4, that's really easy:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
responseStream.CopyTo(ms);
```

If you don't actually need the length for anything (e.g. you just want to load the results as an XML document) then just read from the stream without calling `Length`.

Note that it's generally good practice to declare variables at the point of initialization if possible - and you should use `using` statements for the web response and the response stream.

Comment: Jon,  Thanks for the quick response.  We are getting the exception without calling any length methods.  They are occurring when calling the .GetResponseStream() method which might be calling length on its own. I will try the MemoryStream approach and see where it gets me.

Comment: @Rhino: You certainly shouldn't get it just from calling `GetResponseStream`. That sounds very odd. Is this a public URL? If you could give us a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, that would really help. Also, could you post a complete stack trace?

Comment: I chickened out at this point and back the software to the 3.5 framework and everything is working perfectly now.  Not sure why that would have made a huge difference, but if anyone knows I would love to know the answer.